# Allowing a Stream-KTable join some grace period to find value on table side

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to tune or configure some time tolerance into a Stream-Table join?

Service A consumes messages from a topic, and splits into 2 topics after transforming the original. Each branch of the split does different processing, resulting in messages of type X on topic t1 and messages of type Y on topic t2. In both cases the keys are same.

In service B, I'm wanting to stream t2 and do a join with KTable of t1 to perform more functionality.
However I'm finding that the join doesn't always process, because it seems in Service B, messages on t2 are *sometimes* consumed fractionally later than those on t1. As a result, with a null on the table side, the processing isn't what I expect.

Service A code

```
var stream1 = inputstream.mapValues(...);  // do all the business logic
stream1.mapValues(....).to("t1",Produced.with(Serdes.String(), xSerde));  // maps to X
stream1.mapValues(....).to("t2",Produced.with(Serdes.String(), ySerde));  // maps to Y
```

Clearly I'd rather not inject some tedious sleep before send message Y to t2 allowing time for the X message to lodge in Service B KTable.
Instead in the join in Service B, is there no way to give a bit of leeway before Streams decides there's a null on the table side for the key?

Right now I temporarily reworked to be a windowed join on stream t1 and stream t2. Is that the only option? I'd rather have the semantics of a table where the store holds X until I send a tombstone rather than have to guess window duration.

We're currently on V3.3.2 if that has any bearing on the answer